# Attribute routing differentiates between wildcard and actions with similar pattern

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have attribute of an action like:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
```

And attribute of another action

```
[HttpGet("getuser")]
```

they all ended up calling the {id} action.

How can I route getuser to it's own action without changing {id} attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the action to two different routes like :

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Action1(string id)
{
    return View();
}
[HttpGet("getuser/{id}")]
public IActionResult Action2(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

For `Action2` , you can request like : `http://localhost/getuser/id` .

In fact , if i try below route :

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Action1(string id)
{
    return View();
}
[HttpGet("getuser")]
public IActionResult Action2()
{
    return View();
}
```

If request `\getuser` , it fires `Action2` .Confirm entering `\getuser`